# Sort related objects in Identify window of ArcMap 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, relates, sorting

I have a table `Points` related to a table `Events`. The event table contains the fields `Point-ID`, `Event type` and `Year`. The two tables are related to each other.

If I choose a number of points with the identify tool and expand the tree in the identify window I can see all the events that are related to a certain point. Is there any way I could make ArcMap sort the related events after year? Right now the list can go 2004, 1973, 1982, 2005 which isn't very pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on the related table, you will find Sort Ascending option as shown below:
[image]

This should do the job.

Comment: Thank you! This has the side affect of sorting *everything* in the tree, including the selected points and the related tables. Do you know if it is possible to *only* sort the related objects?

Comment: Sorry @Anders, as far as I know this is the only available built-in option. I am looking at how these records are sorted, basically it looks like it sorts according to OID field in descending order except the first item which is the smallest OID. If this is a big inconvenience (either as it is or a global sort of identified items after picking the option in the answer), only workaround I can think of is to use Sort tool. More clearly you can first sort your related table according to your liking (this will be a new table) then relate.

Comment: OK, good to know. This is absolutely good enough for me - thank you very much.